# Testing for a class method on UIView to maintain backward compatibility

Tags: iphone, uiview

I am trying to use

```
transitionFromView
```

Which is a class method on UIView as of iOS 4. All of the following methods return false in the 4.2 simulator:

```
[UIView respondsToSelector:@selector(transitionFromView:)]
[UIView respondsToSelector:@selector(transitionFromView)]
[[UIView class] respondsToSelector:@selector(transitionFromView)]
[[UIView class] respondsToSelector:@selector(transitionFromView:)]
```

Other articles on Stack suggest that one of the first two methods should have returned true. What is the appropriate way to test for this method so it will not crash when runing iOS 3?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing part of the selector for the [`UIView`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html). You want to use the following

```
BOOL responds = [[UIView class] respondsToSelector:@selector(transitionFromView:toView:duration:options:completion:)];
```

Comment: You're right, I hadn't realized I could call @selector in that way. Thanks!

Comment: instead of `[[UIView class] respondsToSelector:@selector(transitionFromView:toView:duration:options:completion:)]` you can just write `[UIView respondsToSelector:@selector(transitionFromView:toView:duration:options:completion:)]`

Answer (score 0):

`respondsToSelector:` is an instance method, not a class method. You should be calling it on a specific instance of a UIView.

Comment: No, that is not correct. You may call respondsToSelector: on a class method. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1135366/class-method-equivalent-of-respondstoselector

Comment: Oops... that's interesting... how come the docs only list `-(BOOL)respondsToSelector:(SEL)aSelector`, and no `+(BOOL)respondsToSelector:(SEL)aSelector` method?