# How to check at runtime if a class method exists or not?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uikit, uislider

Since iOS5, UIKit can be customized with custom images. We have an app which must stay compatible with iOS 4, but if a user has iOS 5 we want to customize a slider.

Example:

```
[[UISlider appearance] setMaximumTrackImage:maxImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

What's a safe way for checking at runtime if it's OK to do this call? The respondsToSelector: method is for instances only, but here it's a class itself.

Comment: Check this out:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1135366/class-method-equivalent-of-respondstoselector

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use resolveClassMethod: for that, e.g.:

```
[MYClass resolveClassMethod: @selector(trololo)];
```

Or you can use respondsToSelector: since classes are also objects in Objective C.

Comment: "trololo", indeed, as the default implementation of  `resolveClassMethod:` returns `NO`.