# How to Tell iOS Paypal Mobile Payment Library Version?

Tags: ios, paypal

I'm referencing the demo against the library I have and there seem to be some differences.  I just want to make sure I'm not working with something deprecated or outdated.

The header file for each in PayPal.h says:

```
//
//  PayPal.h
//
//  MPL Library - Developer Interface
//
//  Created by Paypal 2010
//  Modified by:
//          DiZoglio, James(jdizoglio) on 5/10/11.
//
//  Copyright 2011 Paypal. All rights reserved.
//
//
```

In particular, I'm noticing that the library has:

```
+(PayPal*)getInstance;
```

while the demo has:

```
+(PayPal*)getPayPalInst;
```

I guess this question is mainly for PayPal, and in particular James DiZoglio, but I appreciate any help anyone who has integrated this with their iOS app can offer.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[You could always do the magic of Cocoa's "`respondsToSelector:`" method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1135366/class-method-equivalent-of-respondstoselector) to see if the PayPal library responds to the "`getInstance`" or "`getPayPalInst`" API's.

And in the meantime, file a bug or send a message to developer support @ PayPal to see if you can get them to help you resolve the confusion.

Comment: By the way both of the above methods both are class methods and and responds to selector is instance method so responds to selector can not be used on classes to check whether the method is valid or not.