# NSClassFromString issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring

Why `NSClassFromString(@"Object")` returns Object class?

When I try to ignore it using `respondsToSelector`: , i get

`NSForwarding: warning: object 0x325ef24 of class 'Object' does not implement methodSignatureForSelector:` -- trouble ahead

`NSForwarding: warning: object 0x325ef24 of class 'Object' does not implement doesNotRecognizeSelector:` -- abort

I can insert `isEqualToString` for `skipping @"Object"` string, but is it an issue or not?

**Update:**

"Object" is really a class. It have 5 possible selectors:
initialize,
retain,
release,
autorelease,
class.

It can't be allocated.

Comment: What?  There is no class called "Object" in the Objective-C world...

Comment: Do you mean NSObject?

Comment: Show the class definition.

Comment: have you alloc that? Class* clazz = NSClassFromString(@"Object"); NSObject* obj = [[clazz alloc] init]; [obj respondsToSelector....]

Comment: There is a class called Object. It is very old and doesn't respond to many of NSObject's methods. You should not use it.

Comment: Thanks to Greg Parker. It's really a class. Can you make an aswer for voting?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If You read documentation You can see that respondsToSelector: is using only with objects. And NSClassFromString returns You calss instead of object. I assume to solve Your issue You need to create object of received class.

Comment: [Read this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1135366/class-method-equivalent-of-respondstoselector) Documentation not describes all possible methods.

Answer (score 1):

For classes use `instancesRespondToSelector:`.