# New iAd crashes in iOS 6

Tags: ios, ios6, ios7, iad, banner

With iOS 7 Apple introduced a new iAd function:

```
self.canDisplayBannerAds = YES;
```

In iOS 7 this works great. But if i run my App on an iOS 6 device, the
App crashes.

In this way it works:

```
    if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 7)
   {
    self.canDisplayBannerAds = YES;
   }
```

My question: is this the normal way, or is there a better solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The better solution is to check if the method is available:

```
if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(setCanDisplayBannerAds:)]) {
    self.canDisplayBannerAds = YES;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! How does this work with this: [UIViewController prepareInterstitialAds];

Comment: Check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1135522/1777634) for doing this for class methods.